# Android setGender parameter not tracked on Flurry

Tags: android, flurry

1. Problem:

Methods setAge and setUserId working are recorded on Flurry Event Logs section in Session Information properly **but not the setGender method**.

2. Configuration

Gradle - Project:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

            buildscript {
                repositories {
                    jcenter()
                }
                dependencies {
                    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
                    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
                    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'


                    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
                    // in the individual module build.gradle files
                }
            }

            allprojects {
                repositories {
                    jcenter()

                    maven {
                        url "https://maven.google.com"
                    }
                    google()
                }
            }

            task clean(type: Delete) {
                delete rootProject.buildDir
            }
```

Gradle - module app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

            android {
                compileSdkVersion 25

                defaultConfig {
                    applicationId "com.xunxujianjin.flashchatnewfirebase"
                    minSdkVersion 16
                    targetSdkVersion 25
                    versionCode 1
                    versionName "1.0"
                }
                buildTypes {
                    release {
                        minifyEnabled false
                        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                    }
                }
            }

            dependencies {
                compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
                testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
                compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
                compile 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'
                compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
                compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
                compile 'com.flurry.android:ads:8.2.0'
                compile 'com.flurry.android:analytics:8.2.0'
            }

            apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

3. LoginActivity (landing activity):

   package com.xunxujianjin.flashchatnewfirebase;

   ```
           import android.content.Intent;
           import android.content.SharedPreferences;
           import android.os.Bundle;
           import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
           import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
           import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
           import android.text.TextUtils;
           import android.util.Log;
           import android.view.KeyEvent;
           import android.view.View;
           import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
           import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
           import android.widget.EditText;
           import android.widget.TextView;
           import android.widget.Toast;

           import com.flurry.android.Constants;
           import com.flurry.android.FlurryAgent;
           import com.flurry.android.ads.FlurryGender;
           import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
           import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
           import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
           import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

           import java.util.Random;


           public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

               // constants
               final String FLURRY_API_KEY = "xxx";
               public static final String PREFS_NAME = "UserProfile";
               public static final Byte MALE = 1;
           //    public static final String USER_ID = "user id number";

               // TODO: Add member variables here:
               private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
               // UI references.
               private AutoCompleteTextView mEmailView;
               private EditText mPasswordView;

               @Override
               protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                   setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

                   FlurryAgent.setAge(65);
                   FlurryAgent.setGender(Constants.FEMALE);
                   FlurryAgent.setGender(MALE);
                   FlurryAgent.setGender((byte) FlurryGender.MALE.getCode());

           // the different attempts to log gender:

                   Log.d("JBDEBUG", "setgender input is byte MALE: "+MALE);
                   Log.d("JBDEBUG", "setgender Constants.FEMALE is: "+Constants.FEMALE);
                   Log.d("JBDEBUG", "setgender Flurry Gender with getcode: "+(byte)FlurryGender.MALE.getCode());

                   new FlurryAgent.Builder()
                           .withLogEnabled(true)
                           .withCaptureUncaughtExceptions(true)
                           .withLogLevel(Log.VERBOSE)
                           .build(this, FLURRY_API_KEY);


                   checkForExistingUserID();
                   Log.d("display user id: ", " user id: "+read_userID());

                   mEmailView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.login_email);
                   mPasswordView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_password);

                   mPasswordView.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
                       @Override
                       public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int id, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                           if (id == R.id.login || id == EditorInfo.IME_NULL) {
                               attemptLogin();
                               return true;
                           }
                           return false;
                       }
                   });

                   // TODO: Grab an instance of FirebaseAuth
                   mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
               }

               // Executed when Sign in button pressed
               public void signInExistingUser(View v) {
                   // TODO: Call attemptLogin() here
                   attemptLogin();
               }

               // Executed when Register button pressed
               public void registerNewUser(View v) {
                   Intent intent = new Intent(this, com.xunxujianjin.flashchatnewfirebase.RegisterActivity.class);
                   finish();
                   startActivity(intent);
               }

               // TODO: Complete the attemptLogin() method
               private void attemptLogin() {
                   String email = mEmailView.getText().toString();
                   String password = mPasswordView.getText().toString();

                   if (email.equals("") || password.equals("")) return;
                   Toast.makeText(this, "Login in progress", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                   mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                       @Override
                       public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                           Log.d("FlashChat", "Sign in with Email() on Complete " + task.isSuccessful());

                           if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                               Log.d("FlashChat", "Problem signing in " + task.getException());
                               showErrorDialog("someming mas mwong");
                           } else {
                               Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainChatActivity.class);
                               FlurryAgent.logEvent("user_log_in");
                               Log.d("flurry", "pos 5 login successful");
                               finish();
                               startActivity(intent);
                           }
                       }
                   });
               }

               String read_userID() {
                   SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
                   String uID = prefs.getString("user_id",null);
                   return uID;
               }

               String generateNumber() {

                   SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);

                   // generate random number for user id
                   Random randomNumberGenerator = new Random();
                   int randomNumber = randomNumberGenerator.nextInt(1000);
                   String stringedNum = Integer.toString(randomNumber);

                   Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis();
                   String ts = tsLong.toString()+stringedNum;
                   Log.d("generateID", "generated num is: "+ts);

                   // write this random number as a value associated with user id key in client shared preferences
                   prefs.edit().putString("user_id", ts).apply();
                   Log.d("generateID Shared pref", "generated num in shared pref is: "+prefs.getString("user_id",null));

                   return ts;
               }

               public void checkForExistingUserID(){


                   String retrievedUserID = read_userID();
                   SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);

                   // Check for an existing user id if not created, create it into shared pref and report it to flurry
                   if (TextUtils.isEmpty(retrievedUserID)) {
                   FlurryAgent.setUserId(generateNumber());
                   Log.d("login test", "user with no user id and whose got one: "+prefs.getString("user_id",null));

               } else {
                   FlurryAgent.setUserId(retrievedUserID);
                   Log.d("login test", "existing user_id in base declared to flurry: "+retrievedUserID);
               }

               }

               // TODO: Use FirebaseAuth to sign in with email & password
               // TODO: Show error on screen with an alert dialog
               private void showErrorDialog(String message) {
                   new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                           .setTitle("Oh oh")
                           .setMessage(message)
                           .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
                           .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                           .show();
               }
           }
   ```
4. Other activity with other attempt to log gender + startOnSession and stopOnSession

   package com.xunxujianjin.flashchatnewfirebase;

   ```
           import android.content.Intent;
           import android.content.SharedPreferences;
           import android.os.Bundle;
           import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
           import android.util.Log;
           import android.view.KeyEvent;
           import android.view.View;
           import android.widget.EditText;
           import android.widget.ImageButton;
           import android.widget.ListView;
           import android.widget.TextView;

           // import android.content.Intent;
           // import android.view.KeyEvent;
           // import android.widget.Button;


           import com.flurry.android.Constants;
           import com.flurry.android.FlurryAgent;
           import com.flurry.android.FlurryAgentListener;
           import com.flurry.android.ads.FlurryGender;
           import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
           import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

           public class MainChatActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

               // TODO: Add member variables here:
               private String mDisplayName;
               private ListView mChatListView;
               private EditText mInputText;
               private ImageButton mSendButton;
               private DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;
               private ChatListAdapter mAdapter;
               public static final String PREFS_NAME = "UserProfile";
               private static final Byte MALE = 1;
               private static final Byte FEMALE = 0;



               @Override
               protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_chat);

                   // TODO: Set up the display name and get the Firebase reference
                   setupDisplayName();
                   mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

                   // Link the Views in the layout to the Java code
                   mInputText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messageInput);
                   mSendButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
                   mChatListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.chat_list_view);

                   // TODO: Send the message when the "enter" button is pressed
                   mInputText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
                       @Override
                       public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                           String name = mInputText.getText().toString();
                           sendMessage();
                           return true;
                       }
                   });

                   // TODO: Add an OnClickListener to the sendButton to send a message
                   mSendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onClick(View view) {
                           sendMessage();
                       }
                   });

                   // TODO: Retrieve the display name from the Shared Preferences
               }

                   private void sendMessage(){
                       Log.d("FlashChat", "I sent something top merci ");
                       String input = mInputText.getText().toString();
                       if (!input.equals("")){
                           InstantMessage chat = new InstantMessage(input, mDisplayName);
                           mDatabaseReference.child("messages").push().setValue(chat);
                           mInputText.setText("");
                           FlurryAgent.logEvent("message sent");
                           Log.d("flurry", "pos 3 withing function
   ```

// another attempt to log Gender her with no success in the same activity:

```
message sent event activated + set gender");
                            FlurryAgent.setGender(Constants.FEMALE);
                            FlurryAgent.setGender(FEMALE);
                            FlurryAgent.setGender((byte) FlurryGender.MALE.getCode());
                    }
                }

                    private void setupDisplayName(){
                        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(RegisterActivity.CHAT_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
                        mDisplayName = prefs.getString(RegisterActivity.DISPLAY_NAME_KEY, null);
                        if (mDisplayName == null) mDisplayName = "Anonymous";
                    }

                // TODO: Grab the text the user typed in and push the message to Firebase


                // TODO: Override the onStart() lifecycle method. Setup the adapter here.
                @Override
                public void onStart(){
                        super.onStart();
                        mAdapter = new ChatListAdapter(this, mDatabaseReference, mDisplayName);
                        mChatListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                    FlurryAgent.onStartSession(getApplicationContext());
                    Log.d("JBDEBUG", "onStartSession on mainchat activity");
                }

                @Override
                public void onStop() {
                    super.onStop();

                    // TODO: Remove the Firebase event listener on the adapter.
                mAdapter.cleanup();


                    FlurryAgent.onEndSession(getApplicationContext());
                    Log.d("jbstop", "onEndSession");
                    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
                    prefs.edit().putString("user_id", "").apply();
                    Log.d("jbstop","user id: "+prefs.getString("erased user_id",null));
                    Log.d("jbstop","supposed to be stopped state in mainchat activity");
                }
            }
```

I would like to go further into debugging and understand on which side Flurry or client, there is an issue. Thank you in advance for guidance,

Answer (score 1):

You need to set gender like below:-

```
FlurryAgent.setGender(FlurryGender.FEMALE);
```

Comment: If I use this: FlurryAgent.setGender(FlurryGender.FEMALE)
I get a :

"setGender Byte cannot be applied to com.flurry.android.ads.FlurryGender"

though I imported the class with:
import com.flurry.android.ads.FlurryGender;
import com.flurry.android.FlurryAgent;
I suppose that I might have missed something,

Comment: Furthermore, when trying to compile, I get this error: "incompatible types: FlurryGender cannot be converted to byte"